# Crafting "fake potions"

Tags: material-selection, costume-design

### Still working on my costume

*[Previous question](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/crafting-a-sturdy-not-heavy-mask-for-shows)*

I would like to know a method for crafting fake potion bottles for shows, i want the bottles to be:

- Approximately the size of an apple
- Resist the pressure of being transported in bags
- Resist weaker impacts
- Don't leak any liquid
- Not considerably heavy

---

Aditional info:

- It doesn't need to be made of real glass
- It doesn't need to contain real liquid
- I don't pretend to craft the "bottle" itself, but I want to know what may be used to represent it (A light bulb, a medicine bottle, etc...)

---

Visual representation:

[image: Visual exemple]

***PS.: I'm not sure how to tag it so feel free to edit it***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the bottles consider perfume or liquor bottles for home bottling they come in a wide variety of materials, shapes, and sizes. Make sense toys in the UK has some plastic play potion bottles on various sizes and colors.

[image]

for a "liquid" gel for gel candles could be a good choice, you will never find a truly lightweight liquid but it looks very realistic and is fairly cheap. it also comes in an infinite variety of colors and transparencies.
[image]

Of course you can always just put a little paint in the bottle and turn and spin it around until it coats the sides that works for making fake milk bottles.

[image]

Comment: Good selection of ideas!

Answer (score 8):

For a few reasons, I'd go with holiday ornaments. These are available in clear plastic, rather than glass, which is less of a breakage worry. They're also cheaper and lighter than glass jars. And they're already nicely spherical!

[image: clear plastic holiday ornament]
*an example from [Michaels craft store](http://www.michaels.com/25ct-clear-plastic-ornaments-by-artminds/10525253.html)*

1. Ditch the metal collar and ring.
2. Fill with [a colored epoxy resin](https://www.google.com/search?q=add%20color%20to%20casting%20resin).
3. Add a decorative cork.

The main advantage of this is that it wouldn't spill. Also, if it does crack from being dropped or struck, the epoxy would hold the pieces together, reducing the chance of injury or mess.

But if you want the internal liquid to slosh about and look very potion-like, that's also feasible:

1. Ditch the metal collar and ring.
2. Fill with colored liquid.
3. Add a decorative cork, and glue securely in place.

That shouldn't spill either, assuming it's well-glued.

Comment: Good idea, but would it resist the pressure of being transported in bags?

Comment: I have made ornaments with these and dropped them several times from a table without them breaking if that is any indication

Comment: I would add though that these can have artifacts at the mouth. I have seen glass strings that had to be broken off. When the cap is on it is not a big deal but if you are not using it understand that the mouth is not perfectly formed.

Comment: @MoonKnight98 Probably. Depends on how many are in the bag, what else is in the bag, what you've filled them with (epoxy vs. liquid). To be really safe, I'd recommend a lining of bubble wrap in the bag (protects against drops/impact from outside), and if they're liquid filled, consider a waterproof bag.

Comment: @Matt This is a very good point; a wrapping of twine around the collar might help both disguise variation in the form, and make it look a little more "potiony".

Comment: I suggest a [wax sealed top](https://www.google.co.uk/search?&tbm=isch&q=wax+sealed+bottle&oq=wax+sealed+bottle) (which you could also do with coloured hot glue) instead of the twine.  A suitable stamp might be a nice finishing touch.

Comment: Another thought -- you could possibly (with the aid of a little heat and a lot of care) make a slightly flat bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the filling, why not use jelly (Jello/gelatine)? It's available in a wide range of colours (or get plain and use food dye) and won't leak.

You can take this idea a bit further:

- [Bubbles using soda water](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/609/20413)
- A slightly runny mix (higher water content than usual) so it moves more
- Use more than one colour, or plain and coloured
- A top layer of clear [with a little evaporated milk imperfectly mixed in](http://www.geniuskitchen.com/recipe/brain-gelatin-74582) for a smoking potion
- Mix in phosphorescent dye/paint so it glows in the dark (not fluorescent unless you know there will be UV lights around -- if there is UV, tonic water works well)

Comment: That would set very nicely! And it's available in a wide range of bright colors, too...

Comment: It would only be good in the short term, and would be prone to liquefying (and thus leaking) at moderate temperatures... but this would be a good idea for making edible potions for parties, or for a one-time use that doesn't have to be transported.

Comment: @AllisonC maybe.  A strong mix, well sealed, should be quite stable.  And you could empty and refill just with a hot water bath.

Comment: When you say gelatin, do you mean edible, (like brand name jell-o) or craft gelatin? Edible might mold over in the long run...

Comment: @Wimateeka I'm not familiar with craft gelatine, so was thinking of edible. The word "costume" suggested that the solution didn't have to last forever, but a few drops of bleach should make it permanent

Comment: @Chris H I don't know of any brand or type off the top of my head, I just assumed that there was a "type" of gelatin that was not edible that you could use for crafts (kind of like how there is edible and non edible glitter). Looking online though, it looks like the majority is edible and animal/plant based.

Comment: Not all "costumes" are one-time Halloween gear; serious cosplay/costuming can involve hundreds of dollars and hundreds of hours to prepare, and generally gets reworn several times at least. This is a great idea for a one-off Halloween costume (and better for party snacks!), but given the time of year I think it's safer to assume this will be a longer-wearing costume that would need better prop longevity.

Comment: @AllisonC I was thinking of theatrical costumes; this would be fine for runs of a few weeks.